# symfony 1.4 and jquery. How to pass variable to jquery function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony-1.4

I have the template indexSuccess.php with  an AJAX function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){


 jQuery('#test<?php $mensajes->getIdmensajes() ?>').click(function(){

            jQuery('#contenido<?php $mensajes->getIdmensajes() ?>').load(this.href); 
            return false;

        });

    });

</script>


<h2>Listado de mensajes emitidos</h2>
<h3>En orden cronológico inverso (más nuevo primero)</h3>

<table id="enviados" width="60%" border="1" cellpadding="8">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Fecha Creación</th>
      <th>Contenido del mensaje</th>
      <th>Destinatarios</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php foreach ($mensajess as $mensajes): ?>

    <tr>

      <td width="10%" align="center"> <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($mensajes->getFechaalta())) ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="<?php echo $mensajes->getColores()->getCodigo() ?>"><?php echo $mensajes->getCuerpo() ?></td>
        <td  width="20%" id="contenido<?php echo $mensajes->getIdmensajes() ?>">   


       <a  id="test<?php echo $mensajes->getIdmensajes() ?>" href="<?php echo url_for('mensajes/receptores?idmensajes='.$mensajes->getIdmensajes()) ?>">Ver receptores</a>

        </td>

    </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to pass the value $ message-> getIdmensajes () to the  AJAX function.  I will have a different ID for each row, but this does not work. But the function works well when I set the value. For example: jQuery ('# test24') and jQuery ('# contenido24') works well for the value Idmensajes=24 . How do I pass the value  $ message-> getIdmensajes () to  AJAX function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not so clear but you wrote

```
 jQuery ('#contenido24') works well for the value Idmensajes=24
```

Also, you have this

```
jQuery('#test<?php $mensajes->getIdmensajes() ?>').click(function(){
    jQuery('#contenido<?php $mensajes->getIdmensajes() ?>').load(this.href); 
    return false;
});
```

So, I think you have elements with similar ids, such as `contenido24`, `contenido25` and so on as data container and links with ids like `#test24`, `#test25` an so. If this is the case then you can simply use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Register click handler for all a tags whose id begins with 'test'
    jQuery("a[id^='test']").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // instead of return false
        jQuery('#contenido'+this.id.match(/\d+/)[0]).load(this.href);
    });
});
```

`jQuery('contenido'+this.id.match(/\d+/)[0])` will select elements with id like `#contenido24`, `contenido25` depending on the `ID` of `a`, if an `a` tag has `id='test20'` then it'll select `#contenido20` and load content from ajax call into this element.

Comment: Problem solved! His solution works very well. Thank you very much. You have understood what I wanted. Thank you very much again!